# How can I role the mentioned user in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm working on a bot to manage roles for a specific server, but can't figure out how to give one role and remove another. I'm pretty new to coding, so I've been searching over the web for the correct syntax, but cannot find an answer. My code is a bit insufficient because once again, I recently started code.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach")
async def sign(ctx, member = discord.Member):
  embed = discord.Embed()
  [
     embed.add_field(name="<:Green:786300903065518090> Transaction Complete", value="Thanks, still being worked on. It would be useful if you refrained from using the command. However, if this had been finished, it would say <team_emoji> (ex. <:DallasCowboys:786222692613226506> has signed <user>.) Other commands will be worked on soon as well.")
     ]
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I need my bot to remove the role "Free Agent" and add a new role.

Answer (score 0):

to add a role to a user, you would use the `.add_roles(role_name)` and to remove a role from a user, you would use the `.remove_roles(role_name)`.

an example:

```
@commmands.command()
async def role_remove(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
 
    await member.add_roles(role_name)
    await member.remove_roles(role_name)
```

Comment: So I tried to add that to the bottom of the string, but when I send the message on my discord, it sends a very long error and from my understanding, "member" is undefined. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: you have to typehint member
```
@bot.command()
async def stuff(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
    # rest of code
```

Comment: and I edited my original answer to show the reflection